# Correspondence between representation of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For the Lie-Group $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ consider the represenations definied by

$\begin{equation}\Pi_1:SL(2,\mathbb{C})\to GL(2,\mathbb{C}), A\mapsto A\end{equation}$

and

$\begin{equation}\Pi_2:SL(2,\mathbb{C})\to GL(2,\mathbb{C}), A\mapsto A^*\end{equation}$

Where $A^*$ is the elementwise complex conjugated of $A$. As far as I know those are both irreducible and not isomorphic.

On the other hand both representation correspond to a unique lie-algbera representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ of dimension 2, $\pi_1,\pi_2$. Now there is only one lie-algbera representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ of dimension 2, up to isomorphism.

Hence $\pi_1\cong \pi_2$. Another theorem says that $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are isomoprhic if and only if $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ are isomorphic.

But $\Pi_1 \not\cong \Pi_2$.

My question is where exactly the mistake is. Am I missing something obvious? Which step is wrong and why?

Comment: The convention (which people frequently forget to state explicitly) is that for complex Lie groups/algebras one considers holomorphic/complex representations and uniqueness refers to that.

Comment: Yes, echoing @MoisheKohan's apt comment: especially, older physics-oriented textbooks are often quite vague about real-versus-complex-versus-complex-conjugate... in ways that I was able to decipher later, in mathematical terms, to my relief, ...  I did learn that in the genuine physics situations, there were (apparently) non-mathematical considerations that made "the math" much more a narrative of some physics, rather than a primary thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you actually differentiate $\Pi_2$ you will find straightforwardly that you don't get a *complex* representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, so the theorem you quote classifying such representations does not apply. As Moishe says in the comments, the fix is to only consider holomorphic representations, which $\Pi_2$ is not.